# AWS CodeDeploy using Github Failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)

Note : 1. Already installed AWS code deploy agent
2. Roles created

Please assist and let me know for any more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can see more information about the error by accessing the deployment ID events:
[image: Deployment ID Events]

Here you can check all the steps and their detailed status:
[image]

If there are any errors you can click on the Logs column.

Answer (score 0):

There can be different reasons why your deployment failed. As instructed above, you can see click on the deployment ID to go to the deployment details page and see which instances failed. You can then click on the view events for each instance to see why deployment to that instance failed. If you do not see any link to "View events", and no event details for that instance, it is likely that the agent is not running properly. Otherwise, you should be able to click on "View events" to see which lifecycle event failed. You can also log in to the failed instance and view the host agent logs to get more information.